# ¿Cómo puedo cambiar dinamicamente el número de un documento de un select por medio de Ajax, PHP y CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, javascript, codeigniter

Buenas devs tengo una duda por favor en el video para que cambie el numero de documento al guardar la venta tiene que recargar la pagina pero como podria hacer el mismo procedimiento pero con ajax para no recargar la pagina.

Muchas gracias devs

[enlace del tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j81iVTt2rB0&list=PLsk-U_4GoSVMz3OzYGN7ZJWOm-rx2FvwS&index=19)

Comment: Por favor leer [ask] y [mcve]. ¿Qué has intentado?

Comment: Agregue una respuesta donde te comparto la forma que utilizo para actualizar datos dinamicamente y todo el código esta comentado. Al final no te coloque código pero busca en internet como hacer commit y rockback y obntener el id del ultimo registro que hiciste para que lo retornes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    // AJAX
        // Esta funcion hace una consulta al controlador para obtener informacion de un ticket en específico al buscar un ticket en especifico
        function getTicketAjax(id_ticket){
    
            $.ajax({
                url : "<?php echo base_url('Tickets/getTicketAjax')?>/"+id_ticket,
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "JSON",
                success: function(data) {
                    // Si todo salio bien 
                    // lleno los campos del formulario con la informacion que obtuve de la respuesta de la consulta AJAX
                    // Ejemplo
                    document.getElementById("form-ticket-estatus").value = data[0].status;
                    document.getElementById("form-ticket-fi").value = data[0].date_start;
                },
                error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    // Si existe algun error al hacer la consulta entrara al error
                    alert("Datos incorrectos");
                }
            });
        }
        // TU CONTROLADOR
        // Tu AJAX anteriro esta llamando a esta funcion del controlador
        public function getTicketAjax($id_ticket)
        {
            if (!isset($this->session->userdata['sess_data']['id_usuario'])) {
                redirect(base_url().'Auth');
            }
            try {
    
                $data = $this->Tickets_model->getTicketAjax($id_ticket);
                // AJAX esta esperando a que le respondas a la peticion que hisiste y le vas a responder con los resultados 
                // que obtuviste de la conusulta al modelo
                echo json_encode($data);
            } catch (Exception $e) {
                show_error($e->getMessage() . ' --- ' . $e->getTraceAsString());
            } //./catch
        }
        // AJAX
        // Al tener la informacion colocada en el formulario y cuando presiones el boton de guardar tendras que hacer un onclick para 
        // que corra estafuncion
        function updateTicketjax() {
    
            var id_ticket = document.getElementById("form-ticket").value;
    
            $.ajax({
                url : "<?php echo base_url('Tickets/updateTicketjax/')?>"+id_ticket,
                type: "POST",
                data: $('#modal-form-ticket').serialize(),
                dataType: "JSON",
                success: function(data) {
                    // Aqui tendras que colocar el ID que te retorno el controlador a tu campo HTML basandote ya sea en el id HTML
                    // alert('Super!');
                },
                error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                  alert("Error al actualizar");
                }
            });
        }
         // TU CONTROLADOR
        public function updateTicketjax($id_ticket)
        {
            if (!isset($this->session->userdata['sess_data']['id_usuario'])) {
                redirect(base_url().'Auth');
            }
            try {
                // Tienes que cachar la informacion enviada por POST
                // Ejemplo
                $fechas = $this->input->post('fechas');
                Si tienes mas datos creas un array para posteriromente enviarselo a tu modelo
                $data = $this->updateTicketjax->getTicketAjax($id_ticket);
                // AJAX esta esperando a que le respondas a la peticion que hisiste y le vas a responder con el id 
                // que obtuviste de la conusulta al modelo
                echo json_encode($data);
            } catch (Exception $e) {
                show_error($e->getMessage() . ' --- ' . $e->getTraceAsString());
            } //./catch
        }
    
        // Aqui tienes que hacer el update en tu modelo
// Te recominedo que realices una trasaccion (commit and rollback) para que obtengas el id que necesites retornar
```

Comment: Gracias por tu comentario pero lo he intentado y nada que me logra correr, me frusta mucho, tengo otra forma de enviar los datos y recibirlos asi mismo por lo que me confundi con tu proceso :( tal vez puedas ver el link que publique para que mas o menos puedas ayudarme en eso pls.

Comment: la única forma con la que te puedo ayudar para actualizar datos sin necesidad de refrescar la pagina es utilizando AJAX